# Nuget prevent generating packages folder in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-spec

I hava a solution which contains two Project.

```
/Solution
    .sln
    .nuget.config
    /ProjectA
        .csproj
        .nuspec
    /ProejctB
        .csproj
        .nuspec
```

When I add a dependency ProjectA via nuget.

[image]

Project structure is become something like this:

```
/Solution
    .sln
    nuget.config
    /packages
         .nupkg
         /lib
             .dll
    /ProjectA
        .csproj
        .nuspec
        packages.config
    /ProejctB
        .csproj
        .nuspec
```

Basically, Visual Studio create a packages.config file and put dependency there. And, dependency is added to `/packages` folder. Also, `.csproj` content changes.(A Reference added which has a relative path to dll inside `/packages` folder.)

I have two question.

1- Inside nuget.config file I have put following line. So I expect nuget will use default local repository instead of creating a `/packages` folder in solution. How can I prevent creation of a /packages folder in solution. Instead I would like to use `"%userprofile%\.nuget\packages"`.

```
<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="%userprofile%\.nuget\packages" />
```

2- When I add the dependency as nuget package. Still `.csprj` file is changed and dll's related path is added there as a reference with relative path. Is it ok? Isn't auto generated `packages.config` enough. Why also this file is updated.

Comment: Why does it matter that there is a packages folder inside the solution?

Comment: Instead having a package folder in each solution, I think it is better to have one package folder in a system and each solution may use this folder. "%userprofile%\.nuget\packages" already exists so I would like to use it.

Comment: The package manager uses a local cache. It will copy the dlls into each directory (As different projects may reference different versions)

Comment: @melih.tt, I have update my answer more detail info, you can check if it works for you. If not, please let me know the latest status after using below method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1- Inside nuget.config file I have put following line. So I expect nuget will use default local repository instead of creating a /packages folder in solution. How can I prevent creation of a /packages folder in solution. Instead I would like to use "%userprofile%.nuget\packages".

You should use below settings in the **NuGet.Config**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <config>
     <add key="repositoryPath" value="%userprofile%\.nuget\packages" />
   </config>
 </configuration>
```

You can check the test result from below screenshot, the packages is add to the "`%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`" folder:

[image]

**Note**: Take care the uppercase and lowercase for the file name and **restart the VS** after add it.

> 2- When I add the dependency as nuget package. Still .csprj file is
>   changed and dll's related path is added there as a reference with
>   relative path. Is it ok? Isn't auto generated packages.config enough.
>   Why also this file is updated.

Not, because **the Package.config and the HintPath in the .csproj file have different role**. The Package.config is used by NuGet to manage the Packages, and the HintPath in the .csproj  is used by the Visual Studio reference the path of the Dll file. Both files are need to be updated, otherwise Visual Studio will throw the error "Can not find the reference..."

Comment: This worked for me thanks , the only thing which i felt missing here is , how to add .nuget folder via Visual Studio and not via explorer.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. PS the `NuGet.Config` file was located in the folder `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`